# Can this problem be solved without trigonometry?

Tags: geometry

I can't solve the following problem without trigonometry.

Given triangle ABC with $\angle ACB = 120^\circ$. Point $M\in AB$ is such that $\angle MCB=30^\circ$. Point $D\in CM$ is such that $\angle DBM=15^\circ$. M is between C and D. Find $\angle DAB$.

Comment: A diagram would be wonderful...

Comment: Didn't you miss some detail, like that $M$ is a middle of $AB$ or $CD$?

Comment: Not that I really tried, but I think I wouldn't be able to do it *even* with trigonometry. Looks like some data is missing

Comment: Related problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159313/looking-for-solution-to-this-problem-without-use-of-trigonometry

Answer (score 1):

This problem doesn't have a unique solution. The size of $\angle DAB$ can be anywhere from $0$ to $45^\circ$.

Since we're not given any information about the size of angles $\angle CAB$ and $\angle ABC$, all we know is that these angles add up to $60^\circ$ (because $\angle ACB = 120^\circ$).

So for the sake of argument, let's assume that $\angle ABC = 15^\circ$. In this case, point $D$ is coincident with point $C$, and $\angle DAB = \angle CAB = 45^\circ$.

At the other extreme, if you assume that $\angle ABC$ is close to $60^\circ$, then $AC$ and $AB$ are almost parallel, and $\angle DAB$ will be very close to zero.

[image: geometry problem]