# Looking for solution to this problem without use of trigonometry.

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to solve this problem without use of trigonometry? It looks like the angle is $10^\circ$:

Given triangle ABC with $∠ACB=120^\circ$. Point M∈AB is such that $∠MCB=30^\circ$. Point D∈CM is such that $∠DBM=15^\circ$. M is between C and D. Find ∠DAB if $AD:DB=2:1$.

Comment: A diagram would help. Initially I thought since $D \in CM$ that it meant $D$ is between $C$ and $M,$ but you also say $M$ is between $C$ and $D$...

Comment: You probably made a mistake somewhere, using trigonometry (just to show your mistake) using sine rule in triangle DAB you will get that $\angle DAB \approx 7^\circ 26' $, and that doesn't look like something that can be found without trigonometry.

Comment: This question is almost-identical to [a previous question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1157362/409), except that you added the condition that $AD:DB=2:1$. Perhaps you should've simply edited that other question.

Comment: They are different problems. In my book the other preceeds this one. I this one is correct while the other is not solvable.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, it would be good to link back to your previous question in case readers of *this* question might find useful information in answers to *that* one. (I realize that there's only one answer there now.) Conversely, you should consider updating the older question with a link to this one, encouraging readers there to look at revisiting the question now that it has more information. After all, it appears that your book is taking you on some kind of problem-solving journey; you should let potential answerers know this ... inviting them along for the ride! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $M$ is on side $AB,$ the angle $DBM$ is by another name the angle $DBA.$ So in triangle $DBA$ you have the known angle $DBA=15$ degrees, and also the known ratio $DA:DB=2:1$ so one may as well say $DA=2x,DB=x.$ Then from the law of sines (which I realize you do not wish to use) one has if $\theta$ is angle $DAB$ that $\sin \theta / x=\sin 15 /  2x,$ from which $\sin \theta=(1/2) \sin 15.$ Applying inverse sine to this gives nothing recognizable, but numerically $\theta=7.435472...$ in degrees. As an exact expression all one can say is arcsin of one half of sine of 15 degrees, the sine of 15 degrees being $(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})/4$ I don't see any way to simplify the inverse sine of half of this quantity.

Comment: This makes you wonder whether there's been a misunderstanding in the problem. Your (correct) analysis makes absolutely no use of the fact that $\angle ACB = 120^\circ$ or $\angle BCD = 30^\circ$; indeed, points $C$ and $M$ are entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Blue Yes the problem must have some error in its statement, since it seems to give too directly enough information about the critical triangle (as you say without need of the other angles), and the fact that it came out an unusual decimal number of degrees also makes it seem like something was not stated correctly.